# Excel/VBA timestamping issues

Tags: excel, vba

What coding or formula in excel/vba can i use to prevent time stamps such as now() or today() from changing automatically in all cells it is inputted?

Comment: In short, remove them. Before saving, replace the formula with the cell's value, rather like [copy/paste special - values]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194765.aspx

Comment: this is not suitable because the workbook is used by others. I need to know what i can enter in the formulae to make this automatic.

Comment: formulae is: =IF(OR(A95="COLLECTED",A95="POSTED",A95="BURNED",A95="EMAILED/FAXED"), TODAY(),"")

Comment: The answer of CLR is nice, but instead of remove the formula hide it.

Comment: how will hiding the formula prevent all dates in cells changing simultaneously?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for shortcuts instead like `Ctrl` + `;` to insert today's date or `Ctrl` + `:` to insert the current time into a cell? For more information read this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-the-current-date-and-time-in-a-cell-b5663451-10b0-40ab-9e71-6b0ce5768138 Note, that the shortcuts may vary for different countries.

Comment: not looking for shortcuts. I have the above formula in every cell of a row. When i select one of the following words in a drop down menu such as "collected" it automatically inputs the date of when i selected "collected" from the drop down menu. However it also changes all other dates with that same formula to the current date, rather than keeping the date from which i originally selected "collected" for the other cells.

Comment: For example i have in cell F8 the formula above which has the date 20/03/2017 because i selected in cell A8 "collected". The folllowing day 21/03/2017 i select "collected" in cell A9 which automatically inputs current date 21/03/2017 in F9. The problem i have is F8 changes to 21/03/2017 also. What do i need to change about my formula to prevent this change.

Comment: If you don't just want to copy/paste values after your data is entered, you'll want to look into a `Worksheet_Change()` event.  All the code would really need to do is on a change, `Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value` which will do the same as copy/pastevalues.  Obviously you can add an `If` statement if you want, and tweak the range specified.

Comment: ok this is a little bit helpful. Im not too sure if what i am saying is understood.

Comment: I think everyone understands what you're asking for but you're not understanding when they tell you its not possible.  There is no way to "lock" the value of a formula: TODAY() always returns the current date.  @BruceWayne's approach is the way to go.